# Call DRF ViewSet via Celery task

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Django Rest Framework ViewSet:

```
MyModelViewSet(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        # do something besides deleting the object
```

Now I'm writing a Celery periodic task that deletes expired objects based on a filter (let's say `end_date < now`).

I want the task to reuse and perform the same actions that are executed in the ViewSet's `perform_destroy` method.

Can this be done? How?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create a new function? Its a matter of `filter(end_date___lt=now()).delete()`

Comment: I don't understand how this will call the functionality in `perform_destroy`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your issue by using [Request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py) in DRF, schedule a celery task to call the request. It works well, I've implemented this before.

Example code:

```
from rest_framework.request import Request as DRFRequest
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpRequest
from your_module.views import MyModelViewSet

CELERY_CACHING_QUEUE = getattr(settings, "CELERY_CACHING_QUEUE", None)


def delete_resource(resource_pk: int) -> None:
    """
    This method helps to delete the resource by the id.
    """
    print(f'Starting deleting resource {resource_pk}...')

    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = 'DELETE'
    request.META = {
        'SERVER_NAME': settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS[0],
        'SERVER_PORT': 443
    }
    drf_request = DRFRequest(request)

    # If your API need user has access permission,
    # you should handle for getting the value of
    # user_has_access_permission before
    # E.g. below
    # drf_request.user = user_has_access_permission

    try:
        view = MyModelViewSet(
            kwargs={
                'pk': resource_pk
            },
            request=drf_request
        )
        view.initial(drf_request)
        view.delete(drf_request)
    except (Exception, KeyError) as e:
        print(f'Cannot delete resource: {resource_pk}, error: {e}')
        return

    print(f'Finished deleting resource {resource_pk}...')


@task(name="delete_resource_task", queue=CELERY_CACHING_QUEUE)
def delete_resource_task(resource_pk: int) -> None:
    """
    Async task helps to delete resource.
    """
    delete_resource(resource_pk)
```

Comment: Thanks! that looks like the direction I need. It would be highly appreciated if you could add a sample code to your answer. Thanks

Comment: Just typed some code as e.g. and edited my answer.

Comment: @Noam Gal Is it useful?

Comment: looking good, thanks! I'll test it later and mark as correct answer if everything works well.

Comment: Awesome guy : )